The request returns an HTML file instead of JSON
The project is written on the basis of ASP.NET Core with Vue. I want to create an API controller so that after calculations it would be possible to transfer data from a C# file to the layout in Vue.
Unfortunately, the result never changes and after clicking on the item in the menu "Computer component" the following error is displayed in the console.

I tried calling the controller through a tool called Swagger, where it is called without issue.

Swagger is a powerful tool in the world of C# and web development, primarily used for creating and documenting APIs (Application Programming Interfaces). It simplifies the process of designing, building, and maintaining APIs by offering a user-friendly interface for developers.


For six hours I have already visited many pages on the Internet, watched video tutorials, asked ChatGPT and Microsoft Copilot how to fix the error, but nothing helps. The fetch and axios methods give the same error. Also, specifying the application/json type in the request header did not change anything. It is also worth considering that it does not matter what is in the fetch function argument: I can specify the correct path to the controller or just put a smiley symbol - the result is also the same. So I need to somehow find a solution to correctly establish a connection between them.
The project structure is as follows:

Below I provide the code for the important files. I will attach more information if necessary.
HardwareController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Management;

namespace systemanalyse_website.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/hardware")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HardwareController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HardwareController> _logger;

        public HardwareController(ILogger<HardwareController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ProcessorInfo Get()
        {
            return new()
            {
                Name = "Name",
                CoreCount = 2,
                BaseFrequency = 0,
                MaxFrequency = 0,
                Manufacturer = "Manufacturer"
            };
        }
    }
}

ProcessorInfo.vue:
namespace systemanalyse_website.Server;

public class ProcessorInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public int CoreCount { get; set; } = 0;
    public double BaseFrequency { get; set; } = 0;
    public double MaxFrequency { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; } = "";
}

Prozessor.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
    <div v-else-if="post">
      <p>Name: {{ post.Name }}</p>
      <p>Core Count: {{ post.CoreCount }}</p>
      <p>Base Frequency: {{ post.BaseFrequency }} GHz</p>
      <p>Max Frequency: {{ post.MaxFrequency }} GHz</p>
      <p>Manufacturer: {{ post.Manufacturer }}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>No data available.</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

type ProcessorInfo = {
  Name: string;
  CoreCount: number;
  BaseFrequency: number;
  MaxFrequency: number;
  Manufacturer: string;
};

interface Data {
  loading: boolean;
  post: null | ProcessorInfo;
}

export default {
  data(): Data {
    return {
      loading: true,
      post: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('/api/HardwareController')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.post = json
        this.loading = false
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching processor info:', error)
        this.loading = false
    })
  }
}
</script>

Full content of the response received:



The request URL in your "Response Content" screenshot is for "/api/HardwareController". (That's also in your Prozessor.vue.) The route you've specified is "api/hardware". What happens if you change the URL you fetch to the one you've specified in the route? (The screenshot from swagger uses the correct URL.)

@JonSkeet, just made these changes to my code, but unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Pretty sure there's someting wrong with the request URL as you receive a 3xx HTTP code. You should have your endpoint returning 2xx. Are you sure that, in your Vue.js code, you're using the correct URL ? You should try to test your back endpoint with a cURL --verbose to check exactly what's going on.

So do you have similar screenshots for the correct URL showing the wrong response?

your frontend and backend run on different ports.  fetch doesn't know that it needs to send a request to localhost:7093 which is what your backend API runs on (according to swagger). By default it sends the request to your frontend on port 5173.  try fetch('https://localhost:7093/api/HardwareController')

looks like request is wrong for that controller... should be "api/hardware" as it is in Swagger.  I'm guessing all non-routed paths fallback to serving static file, index.html.

An HTML response where you expect JSON is usually caused by an error that the HTML is trying to tell you about. So what is in there?

You should try with the absolute path fetch('https://localhost:7093/api/hardware')

@HansKeﬆing the actual Vue app is in there, that means the fetch call goes to the wrong server.

@yoduh, thanks for you answer. It helped me a lot. I don't even understand why I didn't think of this right away. The API was running on port 7093, while the frontend part was running on 5173. I configured the request as you advised, configured CORS, and now everything works.

The answer from yoduh helped me a lot:

Your frontend and backend run on different ports. Fetch doesn't know that it needs to send a request to localhost:7093 which is what your backend API runs on (according to swagger). By default it sends the request to your frontend on port 5173. Try fetch('https://localhost:7093/api/HardwareController').

